# Application is crashed while i try to login

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am new in android and I try to create a system login interface in my app.
while I insert my credentials and press login thie is the json string that i am sending:
{"email":"t@m.com","password":"12345","tag":"login"}
and i got as an answer :
{"tag":false,"error":true,"errror_msg":"tag parameter is missing"}

why is that? for some reason isset($_POST['tag']) return false and i dont know why.

**Login activity:**

```
package com.example.matant.mlnxstore;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.matant.mlnxstore.library.JSONParser;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
   private EditText user,pass;
    private Button login;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //JSON Parser Class

    JSONParser jsonp = new JSONParser();
    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/inventory/";
    private static final  String TAG_Success = "error";
    private static final  String TAG_Message = "error_msg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPass);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLgn);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);

    }





    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonLgn:
                            new AttemptLogin().execute();
             default:
                 break;
        }

    }
    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog((MainActivity.this));
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for Login..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            boolean success = false;
            String email = user.getText().toString();
            String password  = pass.getText().toString();
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag","login"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));

            Log.d("request", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonp.makeHttpRequest(URL,"POST",params);

            Log.d("Login attempt",json.toString());

            try {
                success = json.getBoolean(TAG_Success);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(success == true)
            {
                Log.d("Successfuly Loged in!",json.toString());
                Intent ii = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HelloWorld.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(ii);
                try {
                    return  json.getString(TAG_Message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                try {
                    return json.getString(TAG_Message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        protected  void onPostExecute(String message){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(message != null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Jsonparser:**

```
package com.example.matant.mlnxstore.library;

    import android.util.Log;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * Created by matant on 4/30/2015.
     */
    public class JSONParser {
        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jsonObj;
        static String json = "";

        public JSONParser(){

        }

        public  JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) throws IOException {
            try{
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                is = httpEntity.getContent();



            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                { e.printStackTrace(); }

            catch (ClientProtocolException e)
                { e.printStackTrace(); }

            catch (IOException e)
            { e.printStackTrace(); }

            try{
                // Create a BufferedReader
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

                //declaring string builder

                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                //string to store JSON Object
                String strline = null;

                //Building while we have string !equal null.
                while ((strline = reader.readLine())!=null){
                    str.append(strline+"\n");
                }

                //close input stream
                is.close();
                //string builder data conversion to string
                json = str.toString();

            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("error", "Error occured while converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            //try block used for parsing a string to a json object
            try{
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

            }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("json Parsering","" + e.toString());
            }

            return jsonObj;

        }

        public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,List<NameValuePair> params){
            //make http req

           try {
               //checking req method
               if(method == "POST"){

                   DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                   httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                   HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                   HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                   is = httpEntity.getContent();
               }
           } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
            try{

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String strline = null;
                while((strline = reader.readLine())!= null){
                    str.append(strline + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = str.toString();
                Log.d("json",json);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //now will try to parse string into JSON
            try{
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return jsonObj;
        }

}
```

Error:

```
    04-30 11:51:04.333    1866-1866/com.example.matant.mlnxstore I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-30 11:51:04.654    1866-1884/com.example.matant.mlnxstore D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
04-30 11:51:04.656    1866-1866/com.example.matant.mlnxstore D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae1dfb70, tid 1866
04-30 11:51:04.722    1866-1866/com.example.matant.mlnxstore D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
04-30 11:51:04.805    1866-1884/com.example.matant.mlnxstore D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae1df5f0, tid 1884
04-30 11:51:04.833    1866-1884/com.example.matant.mlnxstore I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-30 11:51:04.856    1866-1884/com.example.matant.mlnxstore D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-30 11:51:04.905    1866-1884/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-30 11:51:04.905    1866-1884/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c20c00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-30 11:51:10.188    1866-1884/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-30 11:51:10.188    1866-1884/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c20c00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-30 11:51:54.733    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore D/request﹕ starting
04-30 11:51:54.768    1866-1884/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-30 11:51:54.768    1866-1884/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c464a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-30 11:51:54.963    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore D/json﹕ Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
04-30 11:51:54.963    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value Access of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-30 11:51:54.964    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
04-30 11:51:54.964    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
04-30 11:51:54.964    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
04-30 11:51:54.964    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.library.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:132)
04-30 11:51:54.964    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:87)
04-30 11:51:54.964    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:62)
04-30 11:51:54.964    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-30 11:51:54.964    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-30 11:51:54.964    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-30 11:51:54.964    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-30 11:51:54.964    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-30 11:51:54.964    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    --------- beginning of crash
04-30 11:51:55.042    1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.matant.mlnxstore, PID: 1866
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:89)
            at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:62)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-30 11:51:57.012    1866-1866/com.example.matant.mlnxstore E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{33439d5a V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
            at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:72)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

this is the php code there is a problem with this?
index:

```
   <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matant
 * Date: 4/29/2015
 * Time: 4:57 PM
 */


if(isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != ''){
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "error"=>FALSE);
    //login
    if($tag == 'login')
    {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $user = $db->getUserDet($email,$password);

        if($user != false){
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["user"]["username"] = $user["usern"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            echo json_encode($response);

        }else
        {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["errror_msg"] = "Incorrect Email or Password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

    }


}else {

    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["errror_msg"] = "tag parameter is missing";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

functions:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matant
 * Date: 4/29/2015
 * Time: 3:57 PM
 */
class DB_Functions
{
    private $db;

    function _contrust()
    {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        $this->db = DB_Connect();
        echo $this->db;
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    function _destruct()
    {
        // $this->close();
    }

    public function getUserDet($email, $pass)
    {
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die (mysql_error());

        $num_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
        if ($num_of_rows > 0) {
            $res = mysql_fetch_array($res);
            $restemp = $res['password'];
            if ($pass == $restemp)
                return $res;
            else
                return false;
        }

    }
}
?>
```

connect:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matant
 * Date: 4/29/2015
 * Time: 3:47 PM
 */

class DB_Connect{

    function _construct(){

    }

    function _destruct(){

    }

    public  function connect(){
        require_once 'Config.php';

        if($con = mysql_connect(DB_Host,DB_User,DB_password)){
            mysql_select_db(DB_database) or die(mysql_error());
        }
        else{
            return "MySQL Error";
        }



        return $con;
    }

    public function close() {
        mysql_close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your parser fails is clearly stated:

```
D/json﹕ Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

you are passing an empty user name

```
W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value Access of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Since your login procedure fails, the parser tries to convert the server error message into JSON which of course fails and produces the error you see in the log. Check your authentication data.

**EDIT** it seems (from your URL) that you are not connecting to your script but trying to access a server directory. The correct URL should end with `/scriptName.php`

Comment: so the problem is in the json class or in my php code? becuase i dont understand where i parsing it?

Comment: @user2393280 the problem is the way you send the login to the server, as you can see in the log above it is an empty string

Comment: can you help me to find where is the exactly problem?

Comment: @user2393280 `private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/inventory/` it seems the URL is invalid. See my updated answer

Comment: how can i check that the url is valid? because when i click on http://localhost/inventory/ i get the follwoing json response: {"error":true,"errror_msg":"tag parameter is missing"}

Comment: first thanks about your comments, but still i got the same error

Comment: so are you getting the same `RuntimeException` and the message telling you that access was denied?

Comment: please show your complete URL and tell me what server you are using (XAMPP, anything else...)

Comment: well I can't tell you much more at this point, probably you have to check your server config.

Comment: i think its something in the code because i have other application which reading from the database and its succeed.

Comment: you might want to use the [volley library](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) for getting JSON data since its `VolleyError` class lets you debug errors easily

Comment: i dont understand where the follwing error occured "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)"?

Comment: @user2393280 this error comes from your server and means <user "" (empty name String) has no access to the server on "localhost">

Comment: but how its can be?? when i run index.php i got the follwing json response "{"error":true,"errror_msg":"tag parameter is missing"}"

Comment: i found the line that failed its httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params)); but why its happend? how should i send the parameters to the server?

Comment: @user2393280 personally I'm using URL-based parameters for my backends. URL example: `myhost.com/index.php?param1=value1&param2=value2 `  You can get those in PHP using [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: this is a post method and i would like to send parameters to the server but for some reason the parameter 'tag' appear as null while i sending it as you can see in my output that i attached above

Answer (score 1):

Check these lines of your logcat  `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:89)` you are getting null pointer exception at `line no 89` of your `MainActivity`

Comment: i found that the json obj is null and i get this message: 1866-2224/com.example.matant.mlnxstore D/json﹕ Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) but how it can be?

Comment: @user2393280 I think you need to check your web service, probably webservice is failed to establish connection with database